# How Rancher private registry setting is working?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

Using RKE1, Rancher 2.7.0, kubernetes 1.23, Docker 23, Ubuntu 22.

We have configured Rancher to use a private account of Docker hub (https://rke.docs.rancher.com/config-options/private-registries) and have lot of trouble to make it work, ok after some node restarts.

I am very curious to understand how this is working (I dont see any imagePullSecrets field in pod or serviceAccount) ?